# Heroku release fails, error related to django.utils

Tags: python, django, heroku, release

So I updated my python code to Django 4.0 and with that, had to remove and update some deprecated code as "ungettext_lazy" and similar.

Locally, the code is compiling well but when I push it to heroku, I get this error:

```
from django.utils.translation import ungettext_lazy

ImportError: cannot import name 'ungettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py)
```

I've tried a few things but haven't been able to update this on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Basically solved it by removing the django-url-filter lib as it's not supporting django 4.0. Since I only used it for a small piece of code, it was better to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by swaping manually on requirements.txt Django==4.1  to Django==3.2.